# How do I repeat a question in a switch case

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a question repeat if the input isn't right. Here's the code:

```
Console.WriteLine("choose a name");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
Boolean input = true;


switch (userInput)
{
    case "joe":
        Console.WriteLine("you chose a joe");
        break;

    case "bob":
        Console.WriteLine("you chose a bob");
        break;

}
```

How do I make it if it isn't one of the two answers it reasks the question?

Comment: Would you mind demonstrating how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop (either `while` or `do-while`) to repeat the iteration but not a switch-case.

While `switch-case` is used to control the flag (`isCorrectInput`) that stops the loop.

```cs
bool isCorrectInput = false;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("choose a name");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();


    switch (userInput)
    {
        case "joe":
            Console.WriteLine("you chose a joe");
            isCorrectInput = true;
            break;

        case "bob":
            Console.WriteLine("you chose a bob");
            isCorrectInput = true;
            break;
    }
} while (!isCorrectInput);
```

---

**Reference**

[Iteration statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements)

Comment: This worked perfectly! My only question, is what does the exclamation mark do?

Comment: @Tabogachi Exclamation marks negate booleans. So true would become false, and false would become true.

Comment: Exclamation mark means negate. So the loop is continue iteration when `isCorrectInput` is false. It's equivalent to `do ... while(isCorrectInput != true)` or `do ... while(isCorrectInput == false)` .

Comment: @Tabogachi read it as "not" and you will get an expression close to normal english: "while not is correct input"

Answer (score 3):

### Use the `default` case.

If none of the cases in a switch statement match, the default case runs.
Here's an example.

```
Console.WriteLine("choose a name");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

switch (userInput)
{
    case "joe":
        // ...
        break;

    case "bob":
        // ...
        break;

    default:
        // This runs if userInput is neither "joe" nor "bob"
}
```

Then you can make a method that writes `choose a name` to the console, takes the user's input, and runs the switch statement - and the default case would call the same method.

```
void GetName()
{
    // Write "choose a name" to the console
    // Take the user's input
    
    switch (userInput)
    {
        case "joe":
            // ...
            break;

        case "bob":
            // ...
            break;

        default:
            GetName();
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, this makes sense a bit, but what would I do with the get name function? Where would I run it?

Comment: Well, how did you run your original code? You probably just put it straight in your _Program.cs_ file, right? Well, do the same thing with this. Just write `GetName()` there, and the function will run when you start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a bool variable, that will determine whether you need to repeat the logic or not. Combine it with a loop and you get this:

```
        bool keepAsking = true;
        while (keepAsking)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("choose a name");
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Boolean input = true;


            switch (userInput)
            {
                case "joe":
                    Console.WriteLine("you chose a joe");
                    keepAsking = false;
                    break;

                case "bob":
                    Console.WriteLine("you chose a bob");
                    keepAsking= false;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. BUt you need to slightly change your code.

```
class XYZ
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetData()
        }
    }


static void GetData()
{
  string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
  checkcondition(userInput);
}

static void checkcondition(userInput)
{
switch (userInput)
{
    case "joe":
        Console.WriteLine("you chose a joe");
        break;

    case "bob":
        Console.WriteLine("you chose a bob");
        break;
    default:
        GetData();
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't spoon-feed answers. This person is trying to learn to code, and there's no point if you just give them the exact code they need. Explain it a bit, at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same results using a smaller code but with a `while` loop instead of `switch` statement

```
while(true){
    Console.Write("Choose a Name: ");
    var name = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    if(name == "joe" || name == "bob"){
        Console.WriteLine("You chose a " + name + "!");
        break;
    }else{
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Selection, Try Again");
    }
}
```